# Use Turnkey Linux to host a Java webservice in a windows environment?

Tags: java, linux, wcf, interop, turnkeylinux.org

I found one of Yaron Navehs great posts on WCF, and wanted to get this sample java webservice up an running so that I could try connecting to it with my WCF client.
Sample: http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2010/01/axis2-wcf-interoperability.html

My plan is to use a Turnkey Linux virtual appliance on Virtualbox, and host the web service on it.

Which appliance would you suggest for this?
I am looking at the following:
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/tomcat
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/tomcat-apache
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack

Comment: Does your Java web service require a container or use the built in webserver in Java 6?

Comment: Not familiar with the term container, but your question lead me to this:
http://sacrosanctblood.blogspot.com/2007/03/step-by-step-tutorial-to-use-rampart.html
So it seems Tomcat is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for testing purposes anyone of the following will do:

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/tomcat 
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/tomcat-apache

Now concerning deployment you can check out the features that each offers and make your choice.

I could not see the Tomcat version anywhere though